# Arrange Circles along Circle without Overlap

Tags: typescript, math, geometry

I'd like to position a set of circles along another circle in such a way that "child" circles do not overlap with each other. I know the radius of all the circles, as well as the position of the target circle.

The target circle will always be large enough to fit all the circles.

See this diagram:

[image]:

```js
interface Circle {
  radius: number;
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

const childRadii = [1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2];

const largeCircle = { radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0 };

const arrangedCircles = positionCirclesOnCircle(largeCircle, childRadii);

function positionCirclesOnCircle(
  largeCircle: Circle,
  radii: number[]
): Circle[] {
  const arrangedCircles: Circle[] = [];
  //for each of our radii  find the correct x and y position along largeCircle
  for (let index = 0; index < radii.length; index++) {
    //find the x and y pos for this circle
    //push to arrangedCircles
  }
  return arrangedCircles;
}
```

I'm not sure what kind of equations or math I should to find the x and y positions for each of the child circles.

I see [that there's an equation for something that looks similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407779/arranging-circles-around-a-circle) on the Math forums, but I haven't the slightest clue how to translate that into typescript.

Comment: In the picture, the order of the circles appears to have changed. Is the center circle big enough that any arrangement is fine, or is it possible that you also need to find a permutation to make them fit?

Comment: @kcsquared Lets say that the center circle is big enough that any arrangement is fine, but I'm also interested in a solution for the later case if you are so inclined to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `R` is the radius of the big circle and `r[i]` be the radiuses of small circles `i = 0..n`.

Let's put the center of the first circle at the point

`c[0] = (R, 0)`.

Тhen the coordinates of the centers of subsequent circles:

```
c[i] = (R * cos(f[i]), R * sin(f[i]))
```

Where

```
f[i] = f[i-1] + 2 * arcsin((r[i] + r[i-1]) / (2 * R)) 
f[0] = 0
```

Testing this with Python and matplotlib gives the following picture.
[image]

About fitting:

1. It is impossible to put two adjacent circles if sum of their radiuses i greater than diameter of big circle.
2. The value of `f[i] > 2 * Pi` means that no more non overlapping circles can be added.

Comment: I'm getting some ```NaN``` return values when implimenting this (not a number). See this from the Js ```Math.asin()``` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/asin): ```The Math.asin() method returns a numeric value between -\frac{\pi}{2} and \frac{\pi}{2} radians for x between -1 and 1. If the value of x is outside this range, it returns NaN```. See this sandbox: [https://codesandbox.io/s/circlesissues-mt6js](https://codesandbox.io/s/circlesissues-mt6js)

Comment: I inverted the ratio for arcsin, sorry. See the updated answer.

Comment: Also does it need to be ```f[i] = f[i-1] + arcsin((r[i] *2 + r[i-1]*2) / (2 * R))```? When I use this it seems to work, but as it currently is the circles still overlap.

Comment: That should be `f[i] = f[i-1] + 2 * arcsin((r[i] + r[i-1]) / (2 * R))`, then that will tangent circles. Oh, I managed to make two mistakes solving quite a  simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way. I tried to avoid the use of the "computationally expensive" functions `arcsin`, `sin` and `cos`, replaced them by the use of the expensive function `sqrt` only, you can try to adapt the following code to your needs.

```py
import math
import numpy as np

def initial_child_cetner(large_circle, argument):
    cos_arg = math.cos(math.pi * argument / 180)
    sin_arg = math.sin(math.pi * argument / 180)
    rotation = np.array([[ cos_arg, -sin_arg],
                         [ sin_arg,  cos_arg]])
    initial_center = large_circle['radius'] * np.array([1., 0.])
    return rotation.dot(initial_center)

def cos_sin_angle(large_radius, chord):
    cos_angle = 1 - ( chord )**2 / (2*large_radius**2)  
    sin_angle = math.sqrt(1 - cos_angle**2)
    return cos_angle, sin_angle

def next_child_center(large_circle_center, current_child_center, large_radius, chord):
    cos_a, sin_a = cos_sin_angle(large_radius, chord)
    rotation = np.array([[ cos_a,  sin_a],
                         [-sin_a,  cos_a]])
    child_center_next =  large_circle_center + rotation.dot(current_child_center - large_circle_center)
    return child_center_next

def chain_of_child_circles(large_circle, child_radii, argument):
    n = len(child_radii)
    child_centers = np.empty((n, 2), dtype = float)
    child_centers[0, :] = initial_child_cetner(large_circle, argument)
    large_center = np.array([large_circle['x'], large_circle['y']])
    for i in range(n-1):
        chord = child_radii[i] + child_radii[i+1]
        child_centers[i+1, :] = next_child_center(large_center, 
                                                  child_centers[i, :], 
                                                  large_circle['radius'], 
                                                  chord) 
    return child_centers
    

childRadii = [1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2]
largeCircle = { 'radius': 10, 'x': 0, 'y': 0 }

childCircleCenters = chain_of_child_circles(largeCircle, childRadii, -90)

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.plot(childCircleCenters[:,0], childCircleCenters[:,1], 'bo')

axs.plot(childCircleCenters[:,0], childCircleCenters[:,1])


axs.set_aspect('equal')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```